# Templatized constructor unable to perform conversion

Tags: c++, templates, c++14

Here is a standalone use case of what I am trying to achieve

```
//Bar.hpp

#ifndef BAR_HPP
#define BAR_HPP

constexpr bool areNamesEqual(const char* name1,const char* name2)
{
    return ((*name1 == *name2) && (*name1 == '\0' ||  areNamesEqual(name1 + 1,name2 + 1)));
}
#endif
```

Then I have a class which uses this comparison utility as follows

```
// Foo.hpp

#ifndef FOO_HPP
#define FOO_HPP

#include "Bar.hpp"

class Foo 
{
    public:
    template<typename T_0>
    Foo(const T_0 & var_0)
    {   
        static_assert(areNamesEqual(T_0::formatter_name,"Hole"),"Incorrect hole type supplied!");
    }   
};

#endif
```

Finally I have another class, which actually provides an argument for the comparison as follows

```
// Hole.hpp

#ifndef HOLE_HPP
#define HOLE_HPP

class Hole {
    public:

        Hole(double dx) : d(dx) {}

        static constexpr const char* formatter_name = "Hole";
    private:
        double d;
  };
#endif
```

In my main.cpp when I invoke this as below

```
//main.cpp
#include "Foo.hpp"
#include "Hole.hpp"

int main()
{
    Foo f(43);
    return 0;
}
```

g++(6.3) with --std=c++14 gives me following error

```
In file included from main.cpp:1:0:
Foo.hpp: In instantiation of ‘Foo::Foo(const T_0&) [with T_0 = int]’:
main.cpp:6:13:   required from here
Foo.hpp:12:36: error: ‘formatter_name’ is not a member of ‘int’
         static_assert(areNamesEqual(T_0::formatter_name,"Hole"),"Incorrect hole type supplied!");
```

Why cant the compiler convert `double` type to `Hole` class implicitly ? 
I am not sure if conversion operator of Hole class would help me out here.

**:UPDATE:**
Updated the snippet to show the error for `int` literal.

Comment: Your code doesn't use `Hole` at all. Are you expecting this to do `int→double→Hole→Foo`?

Comment: What if I had `Foo f(43.0)` ? Perhaps that would take away the first conversion ?

Comment: What reason would the compiler have to think converting to `Hole` first is better when `Foo` takes any type directly?

Comment: Perhaps, thats my answer then. I would have to explicitly call `Foo f(Hole(43))` to achieve what I need.

Comment: If I define a class called `Hloe` that’s equivalent to `Hole` apart from the name, what do you expect the compiler do?

Comment: I thought it would do the implicit conversions, but I guess it doesn't.

Comment: Compiler does do implicit conversions. But compiler ain't psychic. It can't guess you meant `Foo(Hole)` instead of `template <typename T> Foo(const T &)` you've written.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's analyse the compiler error:

> Foo.hpp: In instantiation of ‘Foo::Foo(const T_0&) [with T_0 = int]’:

Means `T_0` is deduced to type `int` (side note: are you sure you are not giving the error when you tried with `43` literal, instead of `43.0`?)

So, the type of `T_0` is fixed from here. Then:

> Foo.hpp:12:36: error: ‘formatter_name’ is not a member of ‘int’.

Which is true: the primitive type `int` does not have members at all, so it does not have `formatter_name` member in particular.

This explains the error, which is as-prescribed by the C++ standard.

---

Now, you mention expecting conversion, is it because of the **non**-`explicit` constructor for `Hole` taking a `double`?

If so, this conversion would implicitly happen only if you gave a double to a "context" expecting an `Hole` instance.

E.g, if you changed the `Foo` initialization to `Foo f<Hole>(43.0);` or `Foo f(Hole{43.0});`

This is absolutely not the case in you example: you give a double to `Foo` constructor that is templated on the argument type, and you do not force the template type yourself. So function template type deduction kicks-in, and it exactly matches the argument type. Additionally, implementing any conversion operator would not change that fact.